# StackAsk - Ask questions from iPhone and iPad - Now free on App Store!

Tags: app, iphone, ipad

[image]

### About

**Now on the App Store, [Download for free now!](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stackask/id492631526?ls=1&mt=8)**

Its main features are:

- Content editor with formatting buttons
- Questions are saved, with multiple versions
- You can enter a question without Internet connection and post it later.
- (Upload images from the photo library and straight from the camera)
- Preview the question's body (like the preview on the desktop site)

Coming very soon:

- Similar questions before you post
- Search sites list
- Get info on tags and find related tags
- Sharing options

Coming soon:

- better MathJax input
- required tags
- post in background.

Coming later:

- iCloud sync for saved questions
- push notifications

#### License

Free app on the Apple Appstore

#### Download

[**Download from the iOS App Store for free ($0.00 ;)).**](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stackask/id492631526?ls=1&mt=8)

#### Platform

Apple iPhone/iPod Touch and iPad

### Contact

Comments or answers on this question.

### Code

Not available, by its nature it's too messy for the code to be of use to anyone.

### Screenshots

[image][image][image]

The app is universal, there is a iPad specific UI.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm interested in testing. Email me and I'll get you the UDID for my iPod touch 4 running iOS5 - `james@jamesrgifford.com`

Comment: How **on earth** did you get write-support working for your app? *(I'm very impressed!)*

Comment: @GeorgeEdison, thanks, it's basically a "front" for the website, but it took a lot more time to get it work as much as it is now. If the routes that the StackExchange sites use to post questions were documented, and a variation of the login page were made, it would be much easier to do write access.

Comment: @Jonathan: Agreed! I tried this myself using a complicated mess of cookies, CSRF tokens, and HTTP POST requests - and failed.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison luckily iOS manages the cookies pretty well, but there issues with that even. If we could have a login page that returned a JSON page saying successful or not, and documentation of what cookies are needed we could have write access without as much effort on the server side.

Comment: Registered for test. I have an iPhone 3GS with iOS 5

Comment: @Geoffroy, thanks, I've just click approve and you'll get an email soon with the link to download the app.

Comment: @Geoffroy, sorry for the delay, the email to download it is now sent :)

Comment: I'm not sure where to put usability suggestions, let's do it her. Could you please add a search/filter from on top of "Select a Site" page? Number of stackoverflow sites is growing, it takes some time to find a proper one.

Comment: @zeliboba, good idea :) I've implemented this and it will be the upcoming update.

Comment: Add feature to specify sites on the app to hide some sites, perhaps like iPad window manager thing? Welcome contribution so hard to use SE in iPad! Hope they will co-operate with you and not break this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hate to rain on the parade, but programmatic writing to the Stack Exchange sites [pre-write API isn't supported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/58444/complete-exasperation-with-sending-post-requests-to-stackoverflow/58454#58454).

While we can't forbid you from trying, you need to be aware that the *instant* someone uses a similar technique nefariously we're going to come down like a sack of bricks on it.

I also know we've seen some more-successful-than-usual bots recently, in attacking them there's a good chance we'll accidentally break you in the very near-ish future.

Basically, I wouldn't suggest trying write at all right now.  It's going to be very frustrating for you and your users in all likelihood.

Comment: Ok, I thought you would say that. At the moment it seems stable. If someone does use the method wrongly, then I might just make it an editor, and not do the posting, and wait till a write API is created (hopefully I won't be old and dead by then ;)) It still gets Captchas if the users tries to post too much, and prevented from posting if the quality is too low, exactly like the site.

Comment: Any idea when the heck a write API _will_ be created? Is this something SE is working on currently?

Comment: @Dynamic a limited write API is under development.  When it'll be released is uncertain.

Comment: @KevinMontrose I would hope 6-8 weeks :-)